# Android alarm running press home button block UI (Lollipop)

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-alarms

I have an weird situation regarding an alarm app. I have an app that is "awake" the all night and at certain point the alarm starts and is the user press the back button or a button in the User Interface (UI) the alarm sound stops and move to the next activity (until here everything is Ok!)

The scenario is: The screen is deemed, the alarm starts so the activity is launched and the user press the power button. After it press the power button again (the activity starts again) and press Home button.

Pre-Lollipop

- The app is running in background and the alarm is still ringing(normal behavior)

Lollipop

- The screen becomes black, the user can't do anything on his phone until he reboots and the alarm is ringing

Did you have experienced this before? I see there are lots of black screen issues with lollipop but I only see "solutions" from user point of view and I would like to make my app avoiding this issue.

Answer (score 2):

This issue was related with the keyguard, I was disabling the keyguard when the intent of the alarm was received because I wanted to disable the lock screen, but I realized the best place to do that is in the method onResume.
So I move the disable keyguard to onResume and enable keyguard to onPause and that made the trick

Comment: Here is another description for this bug:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=94887